# Differing behavior in maven multi-module projects when run in TeamCity vs locally

Tags: maven, teamcity

I have a maven multi-module project on TeamCity. I'm using TeamCity's built in maven 3.5 tooling.

In one of the child projects, in the  section of its pom.xml I set "<target.env>dev</target.env>".

Later in the pom I use the properties-maven-plugin to load a file with the name "${target.env}.env.properties"

Locally if I run "mvn package -Dtarget.env=prod" in the parent project, the child project loads prod.env.properties as expected.

If I configure my teamcity build with param("system.target.env", "prod"), I can see "-Dtarget.env=prod" passed to the maven execution in the build log (where teamcity invokes the plexus-classworlds launcher to do so), the child project loads dev.env.properties, breaking the build.

Here's my questions:

Why does the behavior differ?
How do I reconcile this?

---

Update including some of the information @khmarbaise asked for:

The properties-maven-plugin is being used to load an environment specific set of properties based on which environment the application will run in.
It is set up to choose which file to load based on a system property, and a default value is set in the properties block to avoid having to constantly
add -Dtarget.env=dev during development. The properties-maven-plugin configuration for the child project is as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>load-environment-properties</id>
            <phase>validate</phase> <!-- Bound to validate phase to ensure it comes before loading of local.build.properties -->   # No local.build.properties on TeamCity, so nothing clobbers this in practice
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>src/main/targetEnvironment/default.env.properties</file>
                    <file>src/main/targetEnvironment/${target.env}.env.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>write-properties</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/effective.build.properties</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Version info:

```
Teamcity version: 2020.2.1 (build 85633)
Maven version: 3.3.9
Java version:
    openjdk version "1.8.0_272"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.272.10.3 (build 1.8.0_272-b10)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.272.10.3 (build 25.272-b10, mixed mode)
```

This is the line TeamCity is using to invoke maven, I've only included property definitions that seemed relevant since there were so many that are definitely irrelevant (build numbers, names, timestamps, and other TC specifc, maven agnostic, config)

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin/java 
-Dclassworlds.conf=/home/ec2-user/BuildAgent/temp/buildTmp/teamcity.m2.conf 
-Dmaven.home=/home/ec2-user/BuildAgent/tools/maven3_3 
-DskipTests=true 
-Dteamcity.build.properties.file=/home/ec2-user/BuildAgent/temp/buildTmp/teamcity.build4380238471360533686.properties 
-Dtarget.env=prod 
-classpath /home/ec2-user/BuildAgent/tools/maven3_3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f /home/ec2-user/BuildAgent/work/4508a7116faa21f3/pom.xml -B clean package
```

The contents of teamcity.m2.conf is as follows:

```
main is org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli from plexus.core

set maven.home default ${user.home}/m2

[plexus.core]
load ${teamcity.maven.watcher.home}/*.jar
optionally ${maven.home}/lib/ext/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/lib/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/conf/logging
```

teamcity.build4380238471360533686.properties contains many properties, the value of target.env within that file is 'prod' as expected

Comment: How should I know? I don't know nothing about your project neither how it looks like how the pom file looks like which JDK version, Maven versions etc. you are using? Please show pom file or even better a link to the project... Why is properties-maven-plugin needed? also log file would be very helpful....

Comment: What does teamcity do: `where teamcity invokes the plexus-classworlds launcher to do so`?

Comment: @khmarbaise No need for the snark. Someone more familiar with the tools than I might've been able to identify a common pitfall from what I provided. In any case I've added some of the details you've asked for. I'm not going to post the build configuration for a commercial project in the clear.

Comment: First I don't understand why your build is environment specific (as you wrote)...second why does TeamCity does not simply call maven (mvn/mvn.cmd) directly instead of creating something on it's own? Furthermore I'm missing several parts settings as done in the original `mvn` /  `mvn.cmd` file which might cause problems... But I don't know cause this what is started is not "Apache Maven" it's a kind of Maven... and the question is why using such an old version of Maven? Do you have an example project on github or alike?

Comment: @khmarbaise I do not know the internals of TeamCity well enough to explain its design decisions for how it invokes its built-in maven tooling. The version chosen is arbitrary, but matches what I am currently using locally. It looks like I can switch to 3.6.3, though I would like to understand how doing so might impact this specific issue before I do.  I do not have an example project currently available, but am willing to send a copy of my pom(s) to you via a private channel of your choice if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a [known bug in TeamCity](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-15255)

The underlying issue seems to be that TeamCity uses the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable to pass system properties into maven by default, but properties in MAVEN_OPTS are treated differently from properties passed as arguments to the maven command itself.

The workaround is that for any property "foo" that gets set in a POM  section, that you want to override in a TeamCity build, you have to specify it in the "Additional Maven command line parameters" with -Dfoo=value, or, if you're setting the value in a system or build property within the TeamCity build -Dfoo=%system.foo%.